Throughput performance in cosmos DB
I have a container in Cosmos DB with around 10 million documents. This is taking around 3 hours to load from Databricks using cosmos.oltp library integration.
On cosmos DB we see lot of 429 errors which retry automatically.
There is one partition on an ID and one index. Is this partition key , ID is a logical partition? Can this only write to one physical partition with a maximum throughput of 10000 RUs?
Can we add multiple physical partitions to single logical partition?
Do we need to create multiple logical partitions to improve throughput performance so that each physical partition can handle 10K RUs?

I suggest starting with the docs, as they fully explain logical and physical partitions, as well as offering modeling + scaling guidance. Your question is off topic as written though: it’s very broad with multiple questions (snd no specific programming question). Also there really isn’t much detail. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Are you trying to load 10M documents into an empty container or does the container already have some documents loaded? If so, how many?
What is the total size of all the documents that are loaded in MB/GB?
What is the json structure of the document?
Partition key and Index are 2 different things. If your partition key is ID, then yes, the logical partition will be on ID. However, there may be multiple physical partitions for each logical partition, but this is not controlled by us, it is done automatically if your throughput is beyond 10K RU or if your storage goes beyond 50GB. The max storage per physical partition is 50GB. The splitting can go on until the max throughput per server is < 10K RU and storage per server is < 50GB.
Some points to keep in mind :
1 : If you have 2 physical partitions and you want both to operate at peak of 10K RU/s, you will be paying for 20K RU/s throughput.
2 : If you have 5 physical partitions, each has to have a minimum amount of RU/s and hence you will have to set up the autoscale accordingly. In other words, the more number of physical partitions, the larger minimum RU/s you will need.
You can read a similar question of partitioning here
